# Getting two inline (or inline-block) elements to match height

Tags: html, inline, css

Below is a jfiddle containing the following html.

```
<span class="label label-warning">helloworld</span>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-medium"><i class="icon-copy"></i></a>
```

I run into this issue a lot, where two `inline-block` / `inline` elements are side-by-side and don't match up at the same top. I believe this has something to do with the `line-height` of both elements not being the same. Is there any hack to combat this effect?

http://jsfiddle.net/YfZVS/

Current Configuration:

[image: Current Configuration]

Desired Effect:

[image: Desired Effect]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.btn { vertical-align: top; }
```

Works on this browser... I can't check any others atm. [here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JCG4y/)

Comment: Ah yes, my rat brain couldn't remember this or how to use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you **float** both of your elements left they will line-up, you can then add a **margin** to space them out check it out in the fiddle that is in the **comment**, Stackoverflow is preventing me from adding the link in the body!

Comment: I would like to center both items and the text inside that label is variable. I would prefer not to use floats, even though this is a valid answer. Unless you have a way of centering two floating items of variable width?